# how to do rollback in spring aop?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-aop

How to do a rollback in this case

I have a list that I have to insert whole

Here is my service

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(List<ETP> etps) {
    try {
        for (ETP etp : etps) {
            if(etp.getAffectation().getMessage()!="Pas bon" || etp.getAffectation().getMessage()!="Pas ok" || etp.getAffectation().getMessage() !="" ){
                etpDao.saveOrUpdate(etp);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }       
}
```

And I want that if only one item on this list does not comply with the conditions i must cancel the transaction.

**UPDATE**

Here is my function after having evoked an exeception

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(List<ETP> etps) {
    for (ETP etp : etps) {
        if(etp.getAffectation().getMessage().equals("Bon")){
            etpDao.saveOrUpdate(etp);
        }
          else 
              throw new RuntimeException();   
        }
}
```

When the condition is false exeception is generating but all executed operations the rollback is not done.

Comment: Hello Rodik, what do you mean by "only one item on this list does not comply with the conditions". Do you mean an item which would lead to false  in your if condition?

Comment: Did you try `@Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class} )`

Comment: BTW: The comparing `getMessage()!="Pas bon"` is not good. Use equals() instead. To rollback just throw an exception.

Comment: @chalimartines thank u for u response, I loop on a list and if the message is equal to some chains I do insertion. Now Assuming that my list contains 50 elements and 49 items entered in the condition and the last item no I want to cancel all 49 insertions.

u understand what I mean ?

Comment: @PRATHAPS I try but it does not work except the generator but the insertions before exception are well inserted in the database

Comment: @StanislavL thank u for ur response ,I modify my post if that you can see my problem

Comment: Transaction could start somewhere else. If you need a separate transaction you can add propagation REQUIRES_NEW to your `@Transactional`

Comment: @StanislavL It dosn't work or I did'nt understand what you mean If you can explain to me a little more please.

Comment: You need to read about propagation. If one method annotated with @Transactional calls another annotated method by default it just "joins" existing transaction (opened in the first method). So your method can start a really new transaction if propagation = REQUIRES_NEW. Thus on exception current transaction is rolled back but not the top transaction (which is started on the method calling the `saveOrUpdate(List<ETP> etps)`

Comment: Can you share `etpDao.saveOrUpdate`
 method ?

Comment: @PRATHAPS of course It is a generic function

public void saveOrUpdate(T transientObject){

getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(transientObject);
}

Comment: Have you enabled transaction at your configuration like `@EnableTransactionManagement` 
or 
`<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />`

Comment: @PRATHAPS Yes i did it on the applicationContext file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this solution

```
 @Transactional
 @Override
 public void saveOrUpdate(final List<ETP> etps){

    if (cheakETPStatus(etps))
    {
        for (final ETP etp : etps)  {
            etpDao.saveOrUpdate(etp);
        }
    }
}

private  boolean cheakETPStatus(final List<ETP> etps){
    int count=0;
    for (ETP etp : etps){ 
        if (etp.getAffectation().getMessage().equals("Bon"))
           count++;                 
    }
    return count==etps.size();
}
```